# How to export water simulation/animation from Blender into Unity?

Tags: export

I've created a mantaflow water scene and want to export this 3D simulation/animation as fbx  into my Unity project. Is there an easy way to do this? Beginner level.

Comment: No way. Fbx doesn't support this. You can export each frame as a different obj file and change them at every frame or you can use alembic (abc).

Comment: Thank you so much @FFeller!

Answer (score 0):

Mesh simulations can be exporter to Unity via [Alembic](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.formats.alembic.html), with some limitations:

> NOTE: Supported build platforms: only Windows 64, MacOS X, Linux 64,
> and Stadia.
>
> The Alembic format is commonly used in animation to transfer facial,
> cloth, and other simulation between applications in the form of baked
> data.

Comment: Alembic was already advised in the comments. But... What do you mean by building for windows/mac?

Comment: I mean if you work on an Android project it will never play on the build. Alembic for Unity only supports the following build targets: Windows 64-bit, MacOS X, Linux 64-bit, and Stadia.